# RoR - undefined local variable or method `user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly still new to ruby on rails and don't fully understand why I am getting the following error:

```
 undefined local variable or method `user' for #<StatisticsController:0xb9a20d0>
```

The code:

```
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index]

  def index

    @title = "Statistics"
    @projects = Project.all 
    @data = []


    Project.all.each do |project|
      projdata = { 'name' => project.project_name.to_s,
                  'values' => [] }

      ['Pre-Sales','Project','Fault Fixing','Support' ].each do |taskname|

          record = Effort.sum( :hours,
          :joins => {:project_task => {:efforts => :user}},
          :conditions => { "project_tasks.efforts.user_id" => user.id,                             
              "project_tasks.project_id" => project.id,
           "project_tasks.task_name" => taskname } )

        projdata[ 'values' ].push( record )
      end

      @data.push( projdata )
    end
  end
end
```

**Update**

```
class StatisticsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index]

  def index

    @title = "Statistics"
    @projects = Project.all 
    @data = []


     User.all.each do |user|
      projdata = { 'name' => user.user_id.to_s,
                  'values' => [] }

      ['Pre-Sales','Project','Fault Fixing','Support' ].each do |taskname|
          user = User.all 
          record = Effort.sum( :hours,
          :joins => {:project_task => {:efforts => :user}},
          :conditions => { "project_tasks.efforts.user_id" => user.id,                             
                           "project_tasks.project_id" => project.id,
                           "project_tasks.task_name" => taskname } )

        projdata[ 'values'].push( record )
      end

      @data.push( projdata )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In string `:conditions => { "project_tasks.efforts.user_id" => user.id,` you call id for user object, but it is not instantiated in code above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `devise`? Use `current_user` instead of `user`.

Fix of your code:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  projdata = { 'name' => user.user_id.to_s,
              'values' => [] }

  ['Pre-Sales','Project','Fault Fixing','Support' ].each do |taskname|
      record = Effort.sum( :hours,
      :joins => {:project_task => {:efforts => :user}},
      :conditions => { "project_tasks.efforts.user_id" => user.id,                             
                       "project_tasks.project_id" => project.id,
                       "project_tasks.task_name" => taskname } )

    projdata[ 'values'].push( record )
  end

  @data.push( projdata )
end
```

So: removed the rogue `user=User.all` :)

Question: in 1 place you write `user.user_id` and in the other you write `user.id`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I am using devise. However I don't wish to show the data of the current user I want to show the data of all users

Answer (score 0):

Your update doesn't loop over the users at all; `user` is now a collection of all the users. You need to iterate over the users if you want to get individual statistics for individual users.

Comment: I changed it from `Project.all.each do |project|
      projdata = { 'name' => project.project_name.to_s,` to > `User.all.each do |user|
      projdata = { 'name' => user.user_id.to_s,`

Comment: Which now gives me this error: `undefined method 'id' for #<Array:0xba964dc>`

Comment: You still set `user = User.all`. IMO you're trying to smash a bunch of functionality into one hunk of code: refactor, and save yourself a headache.